# NFS Portmap Program

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

When my client machine (RHEL 7.4) attempts to mount an NFS path, it gets `ERR_ACCESS(13)` from the server.

```
fstab
192.168.120.10:/backup/archive /backup nfs defaults,nfsvers=3 0 0

error
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.120.10:/backup/archive
```

Tcpdump shows when the client requests portmap info, it uses `Program: MOUNT (100005)` with below details:

```
Portmap GETPORT Call MOUNT(100005) Version:3 UDP
    [Program Version: 2]
    [V2 Procedure: GETPORT (3)]
    Program: MOUNT (100005)
    Version: 3
    Proto: UDP (17)
    Port: 0
```

however on other client machines `Program: NFS (100003)` is used in the portmap request message and the mount is done successfully. I wonder if I can force the client to send `Program: NFS (100003)` instead of `Program: MOUNT (100005)` in portmap.

Comment: Does `/etc/exports` on the server have the RHEL 7.4 machine as a client? That error usually indicates that it doesn't.

Comment: @NasirRiley yes, it does. I wonder why all of a sudden this only client is using a different portmap program. What I want is to force it to switch to the proper one.